# Specify Rails Controller Action Based on Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, multiple-domains

I have a single application that supports two domains, `http://domain1.com` and `http://domain2.com`. Models, controllers and views are shared between the domains.

In the past `http://domain1.com/user_type_2/faqs` and `http://domain2.com/user_type_2/faqs` were served up separately using the same controller action. Now, however, for SEO reasons, I want to completely remove the view associated with domain1 and route all user type 2 faq requests (from either domain) to `http://domain2.com/user_type_2/faqs` - continuing to use the existing controller and actions.

How can I specify a route in routes.rb that redirects all requests from `http://domain1.com/user_type_2/faqs` to `http://domain2.com/user_type_2/faqs`?

I've tried

`match 'http://domain1.com/user_type_2/faqs', :to => redirect('http://domain2.com/user_type_2/faqs')`

and

`constraints(:host => /domain1.com/) do
    match "/user_type_2/faqs" => redirect {|params, req| "//domain2.com/#{params[:path]}"}
  end`

Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer is a redirect within a domain constraint. Pretty straightforward once I saw it.

```
constraints domain: 'domain1.com' do
  match 'user_type_2/faqs', :to => redirect('http://domain2.com/user_type_2/faqs')
end
```